# Grub repair: what comes first grub2-mkconfig or grub2-install?

Tags: fedora, grub2, btrfs

I'm on Fedora 37. I deleted my grub.cfg file and when I re-booted my laptop, I booted into the grub boot prompt. I was able to repair my system and reboot. I regenerated the grub.cfg file and re-installed grub.

However, reading into this process has left me confused, because in some websites the advice is to regenerate the config file first, and then re-install grub, yet in other sites, the opposite advice is given.

In what cases would one need to regenerate the config file after re-installing grub? Does the order of these two operations matter?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter. You need to create a configuration file with with `grub2-mkconfig` and you need to copy GRUB code into appropriate places on the hard disk with `grub2-install`, and it is not relevant in which order you do those operations, because they don't depend on each other.

Answer (score 2):

These two commands do completely different things, so you can run them in any order.

`grub2-install` writes (in the EFI System partition)/creates disk structures (in the MBR and the boot partition), so that the system could run GRUB.

`grub2-mkconfig` generates the configuration for a menu and menu items (operating systems).

`grub2-install` in your case is redundant.

> In what cases would one need to regenerate the config file after re-installing grub?

This is normally not necessary.

Comment: Regeneration is only needed if the configuration in `/etc/default/grub` or `/etc/grub.d/` was (manually) changed or if `grub.cfg` is broken/lost.

Comment: If someone "wrecked" the EFI System partition somehow, would that require `grub2-install` ?

Comment: @tmcg928 I believe it's required.